# How to combine Mixins and Protocols in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocols

I'm trying to understand the correct way to use `Protocol`s for ensuring the inheritor of a `Mixin` contains all the attributes needed by the `Mixin` to operate correctly. The `Mixin`s are part of an existing codebase, so will be hard to change the design but I will do it if it makes the design "right".

This is a simplified example of how the code is currently implemented:

```py
class A1Mixin(object):

    _needed_for_a1: str

    def a1(self):

        print(self._needed_for_a1)


class A1UserV1(
    A1Mixin,
    object
):

    def __init__(self, needed_for_a1: str):

        self._needed_for_a1: str = needed_for_a1
```

But the issue with this is that type-checking on `A1UserV1` does not highlight if `self._needed_for_a1` is not defined in `__init__`.
So I thought this might work:

```py
class A1Protocol(Protocol):

    _needed_for_a1: str


class A1UserV2(
    A1Mixin,
    A1Protocol,
    object
):

    def __init__(self, needed_for_a1: str):

        self._needed_for_a1: str = needed_for_a1
```

But still no flagging from PyCharm if I do not define `self._needed_for_a1` in `__init__`. Is this even a proper use of `Protocol`?

Comment: Isn't the problem the same without any mixin involved? i.e. if you only inherit from `A1Protocol` in the last example.

Comment: Yeah I guess the general problem is that the parent class is relying on the child class having an attribute that does not exist in the parent. I thought Protocol could be a way to ensure that it exists in the child.